# Find and Replace word in text files based on name of text file

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, quoting

I have 2 files: A.txt, B.txt

Both these files contain the letter NODE in them.

I want to replace NODE in each of the files with A_NODE and B_NODE in A.txt and B.txt, respectively.

I know there is a for loop and sed involved, but not able to figure this one out. Any suggestions?

I was thinking:

```
for file in *; do sed -i 's/NODE/$file.NODE/g' file; done
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Did you try `set -x` or `echo sed -i 's/NODE/$file.NODE/g' file` for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *; do sed -i "s/NODE/$(basename -s .txt file)_NODE/g" file; done
```

- The double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`) enable bash variable interpolation (replacing the `$` expression).
- `$(...)` executes an arbitrary shell command and inserts the result.
- `basename -s .txt` removes the directory part and the suffix `.txt` from the filename.

Comment: That exact command did not work, but based of your comment, I modified a bit and this did:  `for file in *; do sed -i "s/NODE/$(basename -s .txt "$file")_NODE/g" $file; done`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sapanoia:

This works:

`for file in *; do sed -i "s/NODE/$(basename -s .txt "$file")_NODE/g" $file; done`